# SQL Query, return value from table with no common key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm hoping for an idea on the best way to approach what I'm trying to do.

I have a table with a list of transactions. Each transactions has a PostDate in DateTime format. I have another table holding the fiscal period values. This table has the following columns; FiscalYear, FiscalMonth, StartDate, EndDate.

I'm trying to write a query that will return all values from my transactions table, along with the FiscalYear and FiscalMonth of the PostDate. So I guess I'm just trying to return the FiscalYear and FiscalMonth values when the PostDate falls between the StartDate and EndDate.

I've tried using a Subbuery, but I have little experience with them and kept returning an error message that the subquery was returning more than 1 value. Help would be appreciated

EDIT: Sorry, here is the query I tried. I also changed the title from "with no join", to "with no common key" to more accurately reflect my problem

```
    SELECT Transactions.PostDate, Transactions.TranKey, Transactions.CustKey, 
                      (SELECT FiscalPeriod.FiscPer
                        FROM FiscalPeriod
                        WHERE (Transactions.PostDate > CONVERT(Datetime, FiscalPeriod.StartDate, 102)) AND (Transactions.PostDate < CONVERT(DATETIME, FiscalPeriod.EndDate, 102))) AS FisPer
    FROM Transactions
```

Comment: Can you post what you tried so far?

Comment: Can you put in the sql query you have written?

Comment: post your table structure, sample data, desired output, and What you have tried so far

Comment: What does "*with no join*" mean in your title?

Comment: A join is exactly the right way to do this.

Comment: Please tag the question with the specific DBMS you're using.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any overlapping periods in your fiscal period table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to eliminate the subquery and use a join like this:

```
SELECT Transactions.PostDate, Transactions.TranKey, Transactions.CustKey, FiscPer
FROM Transactions 
INNER JOIN FiscalPeriod ON (PostDate BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate)
```

although this is not quite the same - the subquery will show all the records even if the postdate isn't covered by the fiscal table, if you want that, change this join to a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: I was unaware a join can be used like that. There are no overlapping periods so this works perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **you need to join this two tables with something in common**, or doing something like this:

```
 SELECT Transactions.PostDate, Transactions.TranKey, Transactions.CustKey, 
                      (SELECT **distinct** FiscalPeriod.FiscPer
                        FROM FiscalPeriod
                        WHERE (Transactions.PostDate > CONVERT(Datetime, FiscalPeriod.StartDate, 102)) AND (Transactions.PostDate < CONVERT(DATETIME, FiscalPeriod.EndDate, 102))) AS FisPer
    FROM Transactions
```

remember, if you had this : 

2004-01 
2004-02 
2004-03 
for the `fiscalperiod.FiscPer` the `distinct` keyword will not work